# javascript show/hide div's based on *multiple* selections

Tags: javascript, variables, dropdown, show-hide

I'm building a website for my furniture company and am teaching myself some javascript. My product has two variables, woodtype (buttons), and tablesize (dropdown menu). My ecommerce api requires a unique "add to cart" div for each product. I'd like to show/hide the appropriate "add to cart" (var atc) div based on the unique woodtype and tablesize selection. Here's my code. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

Any help is appreciated!

```js
var atc = "woodtype" + "tablesize";
var woodtype;
var tablesize;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#SELECTSIZE').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '2')
      {
       var tablesize = "2";
      }
      else if ( this.value == '4')
      {
       var tablesize = "4";
      }
      else if ( this.value == '8')
      {
       var tablesize = "8";
       }
      else
      {
        var tablesize = "6";
      }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#SELECTWOOD').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'MAPLE')
      {
       var woodtype = "M";
      }
      else
      {
        var woodtype = "W";
      }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
      if ( atc = "M4")
      {
        $("#M4").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#M4").hide();
      }
```

```html
<body>

<div id='SELECTWOOD'>
<button value="WALNUT">SOLID WALNUT</option>
<button value="MAPLE">SOLID MAPLE</option>
</div>
<br>
<select id='SELECTSIZE'>
<option value="2">2 SEATER (30")</option>
<option value="4">4-6 SEATER (60")</option>
<option value="6">6 SEATER (76")</option>
<option value="8">8 SEATER (84")</option>
</select>
<br>
<div style='display:none;' id='W2'>ADD TO CART1<br/></div>
<div style='display:none;' id='W4'>ADD TO CART2<br/></div>
<div style='display:none;' id='W6'>ADD TO CART3<br/></div>
<div style='display:none;' id='W8'>ADD TO CART4<br/></div>
<div style='display:none;' id='M2'>ADD TO CART5<br/></div>
<div style='display:none;' id='M4'>ADD TO CART6<br/></div>
<div style='display:none;' id='M6'>ADD TO CART7<br/></div>
<div style='display:none;' id='M8'>ADD TO CART8<br/></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi not to be harsh but lot's is wrong here.  I can understand your desire to rush headlong into this, but you really probably need to consult some books/tutorials first.  First of all, you don't need 2 document/ready blocks, and your variables belong inside of that.  Second of all, instead of all those if statements, you can probably simply have one statement: `tablesize=this.value` (or woodtype, as the case may be).  These changes will make it much easier to debug and/or reason about your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could be done differently.

This way builds the select for the appropriate div.

```js
var atc;
var woodtype;
var tablesize=2;
  
    $('#SELECTSIZE').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value === '2')
      {
        tablesize = "2";
      }
      else if ( this.value == '4')
      {
        tablesize = "4";
      }
      else if ( this.value == '8')
      {
        tablesize = "8";
       }
      else
      {
         tablesize = "6";
      }
      
      doit();
      
    });


  
  $("#maple").click(function() {
        woodtype = "M";
        doit();
  });
     
    $("#walnut").click(function() {

        woodtype = "W";
      
        doit();
      
    });

function doit(){
      atc = woodtype + tablesize;
      console.log("atc: "+atc);
      
      // hide all the cart divs
      $(".cartdiv").hide();
  
      // unhide the one selected
      $("#"+atc).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id='SELECTWOOD'>
<button id="walnut" value="WALNUT">SOLID WALNUT</option>
<button id="maple"  value="MAPLE">SOLID MAPLE</option>
</div>
<br>
<select id='SELECTSIZE'>
<option value="2">2 SEATER (30")</option>
<option value="4">4-6 SEATER (60")</option>
<option value="6">6 SEATER (76")</option>
<option value="8">8 SEATER (84")</option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="cartdiv" style='display:none;' id='W2'>ADD TO CART1<br/></div>
<div class="cartdiv"  style='display:none;' id='W4'>ADD TO CART2<br/></div>
<div class="cartdiv"  style='display:none;' id='W6'>ADD TO CART3<br/></div>
<div class="cartdiv"  style='display:none;' id='W8'>ADD TO CART4<br/></div>
<div class="cartdiv"  style='display:none;' id='M2'>ADD TO CART5<br/></div>
<div class="cartdiv"  style='display:none;' id='M4'>ADD TO CART6<br/></div>
<div class="cartdiv"  style='display:none;' id='M6'>ADD TO CART7<br/></div>
<div class="cartdiv"  style='display:none;' id='M8'>ADD TO CART8<br/></div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for this. Works beautifully.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I can see is that you are overriding your tablesize variable by redefining it many times.

Example :

```
var tablesize;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#SELECTSIZE').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '2')
      {
       tablesize = "2";
      }
      else if ( this.value == '4')
      {
       tablesize = "4";
      }
      else if ( this.value == '8')
      {
       tablesize = "8";
       }
      else
      {
       tablesize = "6";
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: gotcha - so how would I get the variable value to change on selection without overriding it?

Comment: In last document.ready, you will need to re-calculate value of atc i.e. `var atc = woodtype + tablesize`. This is needed as in the current state you have value of atc as "woodtypetablesize" which I believe is not what you want.

Comment: Also, you should be using `==` (Comparison operator) and not `=` (assignment operator) in `if ( atc = "M4")`